# No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined - Spring 4 Java configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Everything is working fine when it's defined in .xml files. Now I've started migrating .xml files to java configs. Security.xml is the first file which I've been migrating.

**Security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http pattern="/scripts/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/assets/**" security="none" />

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/app/admin/**" access="ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN,ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/app/settings/**"
            access="ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN,ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/app/**"
            access="ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN,ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/main"
            login-processing-url="/session" username-parameter="UserName"
            password-parameter="Password" always-use-default-target="true"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccess"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailure" />
        <logout logout-url="/app/logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
            invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login" />
    </http>
    <beans:bean id="authenticationSuccess"
        class="com.comp.site.config.AuthenticationSuccess" />
    <beans:bean id="authenticationFailure"
        class="com.comp.site.config.AuthenticationFailure" />
    <beans:bean id="userDao"
        class="com.comp.site.dao.hibernate.UserDaoHibernate" />

    <beans:bean class="com.comp.security.AuthenticationProvider"
        id="authenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDao">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>


    <global-method-security>
        <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* *..service.UserManager.getUsers(..))"
            access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN" />
        <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* *..service.UserManager.removeUser(..))"
            access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN" />
    </global-method-security>

</beans:beans>
```

Migrated **SecurityConfig.java**

```
package com.comp.springconfig;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import com.comp.security.AuthenticationProvider;
import com.comp.site.config.AuthenticationFailure;
import com.comp.site.config.AuthenticationSuccess;
import com.comp.site.dao.hibernate.UserDaoHibernate;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationSuccess authenticationSuccess;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationFailure authenticationFailure;

    @Autowired
    UserDaoHibernate userDaoHibernate;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal( AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth ) throws Exception{
        auth
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
        .userDetailsService(userDaoHibernate);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/scripts/**","/assets/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
        .authorizeRequests()

        .antMatchers("/app/admin/**")
        .hasAnyRole("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN","ROLE_ADMIN")

        .antMatchers("/app/settings/**")
        .hasAnyRole("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN","ROLE_ADMIN")

        .antMatchers("/app/**")
        .hasAnyRole("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN","ROLE_ADMIN")

        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()

        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/main", true)
        .loginProcessingUrl("/session")
        .usernameParameter("UserName")
        .passwordParameter("Password")
        .successHandler(authenticationSuccess)
        .failureHandler(authenticationFailure)

        .and()

        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/app/logout")
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
    }

}
```

I'll configure the `global-method-security` later, as I need to make the current configuration work first. After running the program I get the following error.

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter securityFilter
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:694)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:324)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4603)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Whenever there is some problem with the `AuthenticationProvider` provided, this error will happen. I've tried to configure AuthenticationProvided using some other steps, but none of them worked. Is there something wrong with my current configuration? I think the problem lies in `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` configuration.

**Update**

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <display-name>site</display-name>
    <distributable/>

     <!-- Context Configuration locations for Spring XML files -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/applicationContext-resources.xml
            classpath:/applicationContext-dao.xml
            classpath:/applicationContext-service.xml
            classpath:/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.fallbackLocale</param-name>
        <param-value>en</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>rewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
        <!-- sets up log level (will be logged to context log)
            can be: TRACE, DEBUG, INFO (default), WARN, ERROR, FATAL, log4j, commons, sysout:{level} (ie, sysout:DEBUG)
            if you are having trouble using normal levels use sysout:DEBUG -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
            <param-value>commons</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <!-- set the amount of seconds the conf file will be checked for reload
            can be a valid integer (0 denotes check every time,
            -1 denotes no reload check, default -1) -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>confReloadCheckInterval</param-name>
            <param-value>-1</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>springSecurityFilterChain</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>rewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>


    <!--  CONTEXT LISTENERS -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.comp.site.listener.StartupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!--     SESSION CONFIGURATION    -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
            <!--<secure>true</secure>-->
        </cookie-config>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>

    <!--     SPRING SERVLETS DEFININTIONS     -->
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Path of security.xml is `/WEB-INF/security.xml` which I've deleted it from Web.xml after writing Java configuration

Comment: Share web.xml as well. Also what is the location of Security.xml?

Comment: @BalwinderSingh, update it..

Comment: Have you extended `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` in any class? If yes, post the same as well.

Comment: @BalwinderSingh, I didn't extended that class.

Comment: In that case, you should definetly have a look at http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/ and http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-annotation-example/

Answer (score 0):

When you add `@EnableWebSecurity` to a class, spring security creates `springSecurityFilterChain` bean with several other security beans. As you already have this annotation on your java configuration that means `springSecurityFilterChain` bean will get created and placed in `ApplicationContext` at setup time. To avoid this error you need to make sure that your java configuration is getting scanned properly. Also add your filter in web.xml as given below.

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove everything related to "securityFilter" and let Spring Security Auto-configure them for you.

Comment: No, I've some requirements which have to be handled in that authentication class.