# How to solve No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Recently we made multiple dependencies change - and clean up old code
and our springSecurityFilterChain code got broken
I have searhced online in multiple links
which all of them didnt help.

Just to clarify - application context start - error only happen when making http request to my APP

https://www.baeldung.com/no-bean-named-springsecurityfilterchain-is-defined

[getting exception: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123516/getting-exception-no-bean-named-springsecurityfilterchain-is-defined)

[No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined - Spring 4 Java configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959300/no-bean-named-springsecurityfilterchain-is-defined-spring-4-java-configurati)

[Spring security - org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800523/spring-security-org-springframework-beans-factory-nosuchbeandefinitionexceptio)

[Spring Security: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600899/spring-security-no-bean-named-springsecurityfilterchain-is-defined)

all the above with similar error not related to my case

my web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.company.core.servlet.CompanyDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:webApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/v2/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

my webApplicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd


           http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd"
>
```

My error stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:785) ~[spring-beans-5.1.18.RELEASE.jar:5.1.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.1.18.RELEASE.jar:5.1.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) ~[spring-beans-5.1.18.RELEASE.jar:5.1.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.1.18.RELEASE.jar:5.1.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1112) ~[spring-context-5.1.18.RELEASE.jar:5.1.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:338) ~[spring-web-5.1.18.RELEASE.jar:5.1.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:264) ~[spring-web-5.1.18.RELEASE.jar:5.1.18.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at com.samaxes.filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:65) ~[cachefilter-2.0.jar:2.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) ~[jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602) ~[jetty-security-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) ~[jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235) ~[jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624) ~[jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233) ~[jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.__doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435) ~[jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:42020) ~[jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188) ~[jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594) ~[jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186) ~[jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350) ~[jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) ~[jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516) ~[jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388) ~[jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633) ~[jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380) [jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273) [jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311) [jetty-io-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105) [jetty-io-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:540) [jetty-io-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:395) [jetty-io-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:161) [jetty-io-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105) [jetty-io-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104) [jetty-io-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336) [jetty-util-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313) [jetty-util-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171) [jetty-util-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129) [jetty-util-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375) [jetty-util-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773) [jetty-util-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905) [jetty-util-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191]
```

Comment: Which dependencies did you update and from which to which version?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by adding

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your resource is imported properly, then declaring a simple `<http>` element in your `webApplicationContext.xml` file will ensure that the filter bean is created and everything starts up correctly:

```
<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>
```